# How to run power query in excel to extract a single cell using named range

Tags: excel, powerquery

Imagine a Folder containing 10 forms which are using the same template developed in Excel. The form contains different fields where the user can input data. Lets assume Cell A1 and A2. A1 is the name of the field for example "Name" and cell A2 is the corresponding data field where user input their name.

I want to run a power query where I can extract cell A1 across all the excel files from the same folder into a separate excel file using named range only. Any suggestions?

I know how to extract the  column  but sometimes  there are multiple entry fields the same column.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    let
    Source = Folder.Files("YourFolderNameHere"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1",{"Name", "Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Transform File" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", {"Column1"}, {"Transform File.Column1"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Expanded Transform File", {"Name"})
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

This will return a table with the A1 values in all 10 files.